# Combine two nested IF formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I have the below two excel formulas that I am trying to combine into one statement.

```
=IF(U1="","",IF(AND(T1="SHIFT",U1>=210,I1="BURNABY"),"SHOT20","SHOT10"))
```

```
=IF(U1="","",IF(AND(T1="SHIFTP",U1<480),"SHOT10","SHOT15"))
```

When I tried I am getting an error that I am making too many arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(U1="","",IF(AND(T1="SHIFT",U1>=210,I1="BURNABY"),"SHOT20",IF(U1="","",IF(AND(T1="SHIFTP",U1<480),"SHOT10","SHOT15"))))
```

Try the above

Comment: Thanks for the reply though the above statement worked without errors the results are not accurate for example in the first statement "=IF(U1="","",IF(AND(T1="SHIFT",U1>=210,I1="BURNABY"),"SHOT20","SHOT10"))" if the statement is false then it should return SHOT10 however in the statement you provided if I make T1 SHIFT, U1 "200" and I1 Burnaby the results I get is SHOT15 when I am expecting SHOT10.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workable solution

```
=IF(I1="burnaby",IF(AND(T1="shift",U1>=210),"shot20","shot10"),IF(AND(T1="shiftfp",U1<480),"shot10","shot15"))
```